# Dropbox: selective syncing between OSX and Windows

Tags: sync, dropbox

I'm basically trying to do selective syncing with Dropbox between my Windows and Mac machines. The problem is the folder I want to sync in Windows resides in a different path in OSX (naturally).

Is there anyway I could link two folders (in different paths) from OSX and windows so they can sync through Dropbox?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest beta version should have that functionality. Please see http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20472.

Just wondering, have you tried creating symlinks to the folders you want? You can create a folder which is a symlink on mac and windows. Symlink can point to 2 different locations on 2 different machines.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Priyank

Comment: symlinks only get crawled once so avoid infinite loop scenarios. you have to restart dropbox every time you want to sync symlinks.